# how can I plot string vs float in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I plot `string` versus `float` type graph using pylab?

```
x = ['PARIS','LONDON']

y = [2.39, 3.41]
```

how can I plot `x` versus `y`?

Comment: You need to assign the horizontal relationship to the values of `y` and then assign your strings as `ticks`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many thanks to Myles Baker, here is the solution:

```
import pylab as pl
x = [0,1]
xTicks = ['LONDON','PARIS']
y = [2.39, 3.41]
pl.xticks(x, xTicks)
pl.xticks(range(2), xTicks, rotation=45) #writes strings with 45 degree angle
pl.plot(x,y,'*')
pl.show()
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent way to do this for a single axes? I tried `ax.set_xticks()` and `ax.set_xticklabels()`, and they seemed to be ignored...